# How to make a PopupWindow fit the system window?Just like the way activity does

Tags: android

I want the popupWindow to fit the System Windows,just like an activity.Can anybody give me some advice?

Comment: I tried setFitsSystemWindows,but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Please show us your code with proper formatting and explanation.

Comment: Did you try anything with MATCH_PARENT width and height in your layout?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code in your `onCreate`

```
getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```